# Remove "Format String is not a string literal" warning from xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, lldb

When I use XCode I (obviously) put a bunch of NSLog statements in to keep track of some variables and method executions, etc. However, I keep getting this warning:
`Format String is not a string literal (potentially insecure)`. I understand why this is here, but I also understand that it bugs the living crap out of me, especially when I have 20 or 30 of these warnings making it harder to track down *real* errors. Especially because everything in the string is defined by the system, not the user. Is there some way that I can disable this warning? Here's an example of a line that causes the warning.

```
NSLog([@"writeInfo " stringByAppendingString:[self saveFilePath:temp]]);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NSLog` takes in a format string on its own, you do not need to inline create strings.  In other words, you only need to write:

```
NSLog(@"writeInfo %@", [self saveFilePath:temp]);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for all of the NSLogs that involve combining two strings. Is there a way to do this for something like `NSLog(temp)` or will I have to add it to a string?

Comment: Use `NSLog(@"%@", temp);`.  Xcode is warning you because what if `temp` contains a `%`?  `NSLog` will think it's a format specifier if you use `temp` as the first argument.